# Ideal mirror properties

Tags: reflection

Suppose there is sphere which is completely made of ideal mirror. What if a light particle is induced in it by a source of light? Does the light particle remains there by bouncing or disappear after removing the source of light?

Comment: Yes, if you create a physically impossible ideal situation, then that which you built the ideal situation for will happen. That's a tautology, but not physics.

Comment: The light will keep reflecting until its absorbed.  Even for the best mirrors we can build, that will happen very quickly.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17844/

Comment: duplicate ^ post

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to light in a perfect reflective sphere?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12417/)

Answer (score 0):

It would stay inside of a perfect mirror. Of course, perfect mirrors don't exist in reality. It is covered in this [video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DzRP82omMX0g&ei=BZz9VPHNBoWMNtuQgqAP&usg=AFQjCNGLLXPwjj0PdTWZmeSR8bxHLbgh0A&sig2=3-nRZUi8OZKzlPaMgEF9oA&bvm=bv.87611401,d.eXY).

Answer (score 0):

The photons would be able to bounce around indefinitely. However, if this were really done, the photon would quickly be absorbed by the particles of the mirror