# With a box that has perfect mirrors on the inside would it be possible to trap light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

With a box that has many perfect relective mirrors, would it be possible to trap a beam of light in the box indefinetly?

Comment: We have a number of related questions, although I haven't seen a direct duplicate.  This one overlaps in the subject material: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53225/ and I think I asked the same thing in comments in the prior question about optical cavities http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21301/

Answer (score 0):

No, because eventually those photons will escape the box through [quantum tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling).