# A mirror room with light inside theory

Tags: visible-light, reflection

Let's say there is a room that has the shape of a cube with all the walls, roof and ground made of mirrors, it is all mirrors and theoretically we managed to have light in there without a source. (Because if there isn't light, nothing is gonna be visible, and if there is a source it would just be repeated in the mirrors.)

And somehow we manage to look inside the box. What would we see inside the room?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are photons "consumed"?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13500/)

Comment: -1. No research effort. This has been asked many times before : eg [Is it possible to save the light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240372), [With a box that has perfect mirrors on the inside would it be possible to trap light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66297), [Why does the light instantly disappear when we switch off the source?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173343), [Can light be trapped theoretically?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127262), [Keep the light beam in a closed room, is it possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63211), etc etc

Comment: if you even tried to read my question, I asked what would I see inside not can I trap light inside, plus my question was theoretical, so before giving others downvotes and marking it as duplicate, read the question first

Comment: That is a good point, Mohannad. I have voted to reopen your question. However, the issue you ask about ("What would I see?") is probably answered by your own question : The light must have had a source initially. If the source is switched off, you continue to see it reflected multiple times in the mirrors, getting dimmer, until the light is all absorbed either by the walls or by the detector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the light source would stay on indefinitely ( wich means that the mirrors wouldn't "absorb" the photons and the room wouldn't get dark eventually), and considering that you don't have a body, you'd see the inside of the cube reflected on every mirror of the cube and on every mirror of the reflection of the cube and so on, and so on. Wich means that you'd see yourself in some kind of cube filled with infinite cubes, or a tesseract.

[image: tesseract]

Comment: no, you aren't in the cube, you just observe it, nothing is inside, completely nothing

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly why I said "considering that you don't have a body" . "You" wouldn't be inside the cube, but supposing that, somehow, you'd  be able to observe what's inside it, you'd probably see something like that.

Comment: "you'd see yourself in some kind of cube filled with infinite cubes" isn't quite answering my question, it brings something up which cannot happen, because there are not cubes in there, it is a room of mirrors, the mirrors aren't outside the rood, the mirrors are the room

Comment: Oh, i see... i said that only as a metaphor. Yes, you're right, there wouldn't be any cubes and, of course, you wouldn't be "seeing yourself". But, it doesn't change the fact that inside this hypothetical cube, you'd see something like this image. And also, please, ignore those grey cubes, it's just that i couldn't find any image that could better illustrate what i was trying to say.

Comment: If you have a source of light inside the cube you will see multiple images of the source. If you don't have a source you see nothing. Of course, if you are not there you see nothing even if there is a light source.

Comment: If you have a source of light inside the cube you will see multiple images of the source. If you don't have a source you see nothing. Of course, if you are not there you see nothing even if there is a light source.