# What happens to a light ray after it enters a perfect sphere?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction

I am assuming a sphere which can reflect, refract and diffuse a light ray. So when a light ray hits the surface of the sphere from outside, a part of it gets reflected, a part of it gets diffused and a part of it enters the sphere being refracted. Now the ray which entered the sphere will again hit another portion of the surface of the sphere. Will it be reflected again? Or it will be refracted only?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12417/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

It's no different than light traveling through a lens or a flat pane of glass.  As the refracted ray (in the spherical water droplet or whatever) reaches the back surface, it is once again split into a reflected ray and a transmitted ray.  Any boundary between two materials with different index of refraction results in a transmitted ray and a reflected ray.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was [solved by Mie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering).